# Show that $B(x; \ n, \ 1 - p) = 1 - B(n - x - 1; \ n, \ p)$

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, binomial-distribution

In my statistics book $B$ is defined as: $$B(x; \ n, \ p) = \sum_{y = 0}^{x}b(y; \ n, \ p) = \sum_{y = 0}^{x}{n \choose y}p^{y}(1 - p)^{n - y}$$

I want to show that: $$B(x; \ n, \ 1 - p) = 1 - B(n - x - 1; \ n, \ p)$$

The hint that I got was that at most $x$ successes is equivalent to at least $(n - x)$ failures in the binomial probability distribution. I tried to rewrite it but I get stuck in nowhere. Appreciate any help, cheers.

Comment: Just a remark: Your book should not use $x$ as a variable name, normally $x$ is used for continuous variables. By the way, this distribution is called Bernoulli distribution. I think this is a simple plug in and verify exercise.

Comment: @MrYouMath By the way, this distribution is called binomial distribution, not Bernoulli distribution.

Comment: @Did: Really? I learned it as Bernoulli distribution/Binomial distribution because it is based on Bernoulli experiments.

Comment: @MrYouMath Yes, really (except if $n=1$, of course). But I am curious, when somebody says something that challenges your beliefs, [you never check](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Bernoulli_distribution)?

Comment: @Did: I like to relate people's names to mathematical concepts, that is my way of giving credit to them for their contributions to science. And as it seems that one of the Bernoulli's really did derive it, I will stick to Bernoulli distribution. Next time I will write Bernoulli distribution (aka Binomial distribution) :D.

Comment: @MrYouMath Did you check the link?

Comment: @Did: What do you mean? In the history section they mention that it was derived by Bernoulli. That is enough for me to continue to call it Bernoulli’s binomial distribution:).

Comment: @MrYouMath ...In opposition to what they explicitely state on the page, and to the common usage in the mathematical community as a whole. Your call.

Comment: @Amoz Are you interested in an explanation based on the **structure** of these distributions, or is the (rather terrible) computational approach below satisfying to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
1 - B(n - x - 1; \ n, \ p)  = & 1 - \sum_{y = n-x-1}^{n}{n \choose y}p^{y}(1 - p)^{n - y}
\\ = & \sum_{y = 0}^{n}{n \choose y}p^{y}(1 - p)^{n - y} - \sum_{y = n-x-1}^{n}{n \choose y}p^{y}(1 - p)^{n - y}
\\ = & \sum_{y = n-x}^{n}{n \choose y}p^{y}(1 - p)^{n - y}
\\ = & \binom{n}{n-x}p^{n-x}(1-p)^{x} + \binom{n}{n-x+1}p^{n-x+1}(1-p)^{x-1} + ... + \binom{n}{n}p^{n}(1-p)^{0}
\\=& \binom{n}{n-(n-x)}p^{n-x}(1-p)^{x} + \binom{n}{n-(n-x+1)}p^{n-x+1}(1-p)^{x-1} + ... + \binom{n}{n-(n)}p^{n}(1-p)^{0}
\\=& \binom{n}{x}p^{n-x}(1-p)^{x} + \binom{n}{x-1}p^{n-x+1}(1-p)^{x-1} + ... + \binom{n}{0}p^{n}(1-p)^{0}
\\ =& \sum_{y = 0}^{x}{n \choose y}(1-p)^{y}p^{n - y}
\\ =& B(x; \ n, \ 1 - p)
\end{align}

Comment: How do you get from line 2 to line 3? Can't make it work.

Comment: @Amoz : I add some explanations.